# Bootstrap vue datepicker: value date shows outside input field

Tags: forms, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

using veevalidate
when I inspect it: the date shows in a label under the input

```
<b-form-datepicker
                      :name="el.label"
                      :ref="el.field"
                      v-if="el.type === 'date' || el.type === 
                     'datetime'"
                      v-model="value[el.field]"
                      :placeholder="el.placeholder"
                      v-validate="el.rules"
></b-form-datepicker>
```

[inspection & view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDRzY.png)

Comment: @kritstistina did you find a solution? I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I had not included the bootstrap-vue css.
Issue was resolved after including below below css.

```
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
```